# orderBy $filter blocks ng-repeat list update after item deletion (splice)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a list displayed with ng-repeat and ordered by name desc.

Each item has a `item-delete` directive on it that holds the `$index` and on item click I delete the item from the list using given `index` with `splice` function and then I update the list - which doesn't work!

From my debugging results that the problem occurs after `orderBy` filter is called inside directive. If I directly remove the item like this `scope.list.splice(index, 1)` it works, but the removed item is not the correct one as items are ordered by ng-repeat, so I have to order them the same way and after that I can perform a correct deletion.

A workaround is to `$emit` the new list and update the scope inside controller, but I don't wanna do this. Tested & working (see snippet).

A `scope.$apply` will run into a `digest already in progress` error (because this part of code is inside a promise in my app) & without `$timeout` the list won't update when it's working (with `noFilter` filter, for eg.).

*I'm using a directive to remove a item from list because I'm doing a lot more on item click (DOM changes, service calls) and the controller isn't the place for that (in case you're thinking why I'm not doing this through controller).

Also, a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjhWMzyszE61fVcvBzMq).

```js
// JS

var APP = angular.module('APP', []);

APP.controller('Home', function($scope, $filter){
  var objData = {
    "1": {  id: 1, name: "Abc" },
    "2": {  id: 2,  name: "Bbc" },
    "3": {  id: 3, name: "Fea"  },
    "4": {  id: 4,  name: "Dbc" }
  };
  
  $scope.list = $filter('objToArr')(objData);
  
  //part of workaround...
  $scope.$on('listUpdate', function(evt, data){
    $scope.list = data;
  })
  
}); 

APP.directive('itemDelete', function($filter, $timeout){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      var delIndex;
      attrs.$observe('itemDelete', function(val){
        delIndex = val;
      });
      
      angular.element(el).click(function(){
        console.log('deleting item index '+ delIndex);
        console.log('list length before ' + scope.list.length);
        
        //delete item from ng-repeat ordered list
        $timeout(function(){
          var listOrdered = $filter('orderBy')(scope.list, '-name'); //replace 'orderBy' with 'noFilter' -> it works, but removes wrong item!
          //var listOrdered = scope.list; // uncomment & comment line before this -> it works,  but removes wrong item!
          listOrdered.splice(delIndex,1);
          scope.list = listOrdered;
          
          //workaround...
          //scope.$emit('listUpdate', scope.list);
          
          console.log('list length after ' + scope.list.length);
        });
        
      });
      
    }
  }
})

APP.filter('objToArr', function(){
  return function(input){
    var arrData = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(arr, key){
      arrData.push(arr);
    });
    
    return arrData;
  }
});

APP.filter('noFilter', function(){
  return function(input){
    return input;
  }
});
```

```css
ul li{ display: block;  margin-bottom: 4px; background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px; }
ul{ list-style:none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="APP">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15" data-require="angular.js@1.3.15"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Home">
    <h4>Click on item - remove from list</h4>
    <ul>
      <li item-delete="{{ $index }}" ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy:'-name'">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there a reason that you are trying to build a complex directive to handle this task? there are much easier ways to do what you are showing here....

Comment: icon changing, disable everything (location change, all page actions), service call and wait for promise and based on that (win & err) I make changes to model & DOM. This is what's happening inside this directive. Give me some examples of other ways to make that and maybe I could adapt to my needs.

Comment: I could call the service and wait for answer in controller using ng-click and when i'll have it i could change icons with ng-class...but I'm curious why isn't working this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
scope.list = listOrdered;
```

That line define a new `list` property on the chlid scope instead of changing the actual list, which is a property of the parent scope. (so doing scope.$parent.list = listOrdered works fine..).

You can solve it by putting the list in an object, which will keep the referneces in sync:

```
$scope.objList = { list: $filter('objToArr')(objData) };

var listOrdered = $filter('orderBy')(scope.objList.list, '-name'); //replace 'orderBy' with 'noFilter' -> it works, but removes wrong item!
listOrdered.splice(delIndex,1);
scope.objList.list = listOrdered;
```

In your HTML:

```
<li item-delete="{{ $index }}" ng-repeat="item in objList.list | orderBy:'-name'">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzTHWkYJSuRgTVDpr5q4?p=preview)

Comment: ok... but if you put this ``$timeout(function(){ var listOrdered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.list, '-name'); listOrdered.splice(2,1);  $scope.list = listOrdered; },2000);`` inside controller, it works. Why?

Comment: its working becuase you change the property on the same scope of the list. i've cleared my answer about this.

Comment: check here for more info: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: got it! I remember I tried ``scope.$parent`` within my app and didn't work, but here works... I'll run some tests again later. Great explanation, thanks!

Comment: ... and my line with ``noFilter`` filter was working because I wasn't changing anything, I was just returning what was given. Still... I have another page where I'm doing pretty much the same, but instead of ``orderBy`` I have a custom orderBy filter (that returns a modified list) and the lists are kept in sync.

Comment: hmm could be more than one $parent in the chain.. hard to tell without seeing the code

Comment: i'll be back with a more complete code + the code of that page where the lists are synchronized even after a filter is applied inside a directive. it's a little bit weird.